# How can I jump to a component in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin application with multiple tabs. When I do something in one tab I want it to automatically jump to another tab in the application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use    `Tabsheet.setSelectedTab(Component c)`